# Can I use "router" in roadhog's "proxy" prop?

Tags: antd

When I config my .roadhogrc, roadhog's doc said I can set "proxy" prop same as [webpack-dev-server#proxy](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#proxy).

I add a "router" prop, then my page can not load, due to the "index.css" timeout.

So, how to use "proxy" in .roadhogrc?
or any way to change the api to test env in localhost?

I can't  find "dva" or "roadhog" tag, so sorry to use "antd" tag.

```
{
  "entry": "src/index.js",
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "extraBabelPlugins": [
        "dva-hmr",
        "transform-runtime",
         ["import", { "libraryName": "antd", "style": "css" }]
      ],
      "proxy":{
        "router":{
          "http://api.eshop.corploft.com" : "http://test.corploft.com"
        }
      }
    },
    "production": {
      "extraBabelPlugins": [
        "transform-runtime",
        ["import", { "libraryName": "antd", "style": "css" }]
      ],
      "outputPath":"build/yijiayi"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I told a joke...

All the proxy and mock settings are acting on localhost network, so I can only change the requests to local server. If I want to change a request to other servers, all above settings has no help.

SwitchyOmega (in Chrome App Store) or [ihosts](https://h.ihosts.toolinbox.net/cn/) can help.